# SQLAlchemy limit results

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

imagine I have a simple database like this

[image: ERD]

I want to execute this SQL query using SQLAlchemy to get only 10 latest results of toys with certain Child_id belonging to some parent.

```
toys = Toy.query.filter(Toy.child_id == 77).filter(Child.parent_id == 'parent1').order_by(Toys.id.desc()).limit(limit).all()
```

But if I execute this, I get only 1 result.

Echoing the query, I get

```
"SELECT toys.id AS toys_id, toys.toy_type AS toy_type FROM toys, children WHERE toys.child_id = 77 ORDER BY records.id DESC LIMIT 10;"
```

Executing this raw query, I get 10 of the same toys results.

There is a total of 15 children of this parent. If I put the query limit to 20, I get 15 of the same toys results and 5 of the same different toys results. It always gives the number of the same toys results as the amount of children.

So I guess it has something to do with the joining the tables and limiting the results...

Comment: You are right, it produces the same SQL query. I put more info to the initial post to edit section.

Comment: snakecharmerb, I'm sure

Comment: It screams at me "SAWarning: SELECT statement has a cartesian product between FROM element(s) "toys" and FROM element "children".  Apply join condition(s) between each element to resolve."

It might have to do something with that

Comment: I'm starting to uderstand the problem. 
"SELECT toys.id AS toys_id, toys.toy_type AS toy_type FROM toys, children WHERE records.child_id = 77 ORDER BY records.id DESC LIMIT 10;"

Gives me 10 of the same records. There are total of 15 children of this parent. If I put limit to 20, it gives me 15 of same records + 5 same different records.

So that's why "toys = Toys.query.filter(Toys.Child_id == 77).limit(10).all()" gives me only 1 record. If I set up the limit to 45, I get 3 records. It somehow limits something else.

Answer (score 0):

It's solved. I didn't use join statement, that's why it didn't work.

```
toys = (Toy.query
           .join(Child)
           .join(Parent)
           .filter(Parent.name == 'parent1').filter(Toy.child_id == 77)
).limit(10).all()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

I'd expect you to do something like `Session.query(Toys).filter(Child_id == 77).limit(10).all()` or something like that.